# Is there a jQuery method that allow me to change color when my mouse enters an element's area?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, but it is not working.

```
$('.exampleClass').on('mouseenter', ()=> {
 $('.exampleClass').css('color', 'Black');
});
```

Comment: You can do it with CSS `.exampleClass:hover { color: black; }`

Comment: you are doing it alright , what error is at your end do you want to change the font color or the background color

Comment: The only thing I'll add to Alon's comment is that we should always use CSS before jQuery. For better browser compatibility. JS is somewhat universal, but not nearly as universal as CSS.

Comment: Mouseenter and hover are not the same, hover is a temporary state. Of course, it would be nice in that case to use the `one()` method. And yes, the code seems right, so we might need more information/code.

Comment: Both above comments are correct. I voted to close this question as unclear because you didn't provide the relevant HTML and you should also explain what exactly "not working" (But I bet that all the elements with that class get black color instead the one you actually hovering above because you're not using `$(this)` in the event). Read about creating a [mcve]

Comment: i agree with @René too and yes it should be closed if not updated